# Linting errors for ref()'s within Vue 3 templates when using setup with TypeScript <setup lang="ts" script>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

I've spent long days trying to find out why is it that the linter complains when I am not using `.value` within templates for `Ref` types, which isn't required within the template section  a [SFC file](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html)!

The code runs alright, it's just the linter the complains:

[image]

And if I go ahead and "fix" the error by using `count.value.toFixed(2)` within the template, the linter doesn't complain anymore but the doesn't work either.

I've duplicated the [eslint-plugin-vue demo playground](https://ota-meshi.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue-demo/#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) for this code, to no avail.

Strangely, if I either remove the `lang="ts"` part (and lose all of the TypeScript features) or the `setup` (and refactor to expose the `count` variable), the linting error goes away.

My `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  parserOptions: {
    parser: require.resolve('@typescript-eslint/parser'),
    extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
  },

  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
  },

  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential', // Priority A: Essential (Error Prevention)
    'prettier',
  ],

  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'vue',
  ],

  globals: {
    ga: 'readonly', // Google Analytics
    cordova: 'readonly',
    __statics: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_SERVER__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_CLIENT__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_PWA__: 'readonly',
    process: 'readonly',
    Capacitor: 'readonly',
    chrome: 'readonly',
  },

  rules: {
    'prefer-promise-reject-errors': 'off',
    quotes: ['warn', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
};
```

And my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "app/*": ["*"],
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
      "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "boot/*": ["src/boot/*"],
      "stores/*": ["src/stores/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", ".quasar", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Here, it's a TS issue and not ESlint. If you don't mind disabling it, you can just do so. Otherwise, the TS config will be needed to debug it further.

Comment: Hey @kissu, it seemed to me like a lint issue.  Anyhow, I've just added my TS config settings  :D

Comment: Your original code works fine in the [SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9T8tqwzAQ/JVFlyQQS7RH4xR66Vfo4trr1CF6sFq7BaF/76oupSQQnXZmZ0azWb3GqNcFVau6NNAcGRLyEuHa+/PJKk5WvVg/uxiIIQPhBAUmCg52YttZb/0QfGIYwuIZTlWxfzpY35ktT9wCGF289owVcTfOqwwgL+fNqDm8zV847p8PUErddWZTdebPq45qK9K4PupLCl5q5yq2vwtp28IPUzkpWLFVH8wxtcakaajHXpIOdDYyaZK/Z4cak2veKXwmJAm26vgvwwi5IjWEfkRCepR5I73LrbFyXlHlGxPag4I=).

Comment: Definitely a TypeScript error. Notice `ts(2339)` in the error message. That's the error source. Are you using Volar?

Comment: Hi @tony19.  Yes, the code builds and renders alright.

Comment: I do have the Vue official latest versions of both, [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) and its [TypeScript Vue Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin).

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction? Might need to see this in GitPod.

Comment: @tony19, your comment actually got me thinking... I remembered that when I first created the project scaffold I didn't have this issue.  So I went all over again the creation process, and granted, no problem.  That led me the actual problem and solution, which I just posted as answer...  so, thank you I guess!  

Answer (score 1):

So, answering to my own question...  It turned out that in my repo I had a "legacy code" subdirectory that was right under my current active codebase, and this was conflicting in a number of ways.

Once I rearranged the directories hierarchy, the problem was solved  ✅

I couldn't quite put my finger as to what file or setting was causing the trouble; but not only the problem was gone after I moved the legacy code out of the way, but also project initialization in VS Code was a lot faster.

### Moral of the Story

**Pay close attention to directory hierarchy in [monorepos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo)!**